# How do I stop nginx from thinking image URLs are actual files?

Tags: http, url, nginx

*sorry for the terrible title; it's hard to explain*

I have a search function built into my site which is used like this:

```
http://www.example.com/search/queryhere
```

The problem is that when I try searching for a filename, eg.:

```
http://www.example.com/search/hello.jpg
```

I get a nginx 404 page, supposedly because `search/hello.jpg` is trying to be opened. A workaround is to add a forward slash to the request path, but I want a more permanent solution. How do I fix this?

```
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }
```

Comment: show your nginx config please

Comment: @Alp added relevant part to the question

Comment: By the way, if anyone is coming from Google trying to figure out why Nginx is treating certain URLs as static files, be sure you have escaped the period in front of the file extensions ruleset e.g. `\.` and not just `.` otherwise it acts like a wildcard and might match with all kinds of random URLs on your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell nginx to only do the extra directives for **existing** files:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
  if (-f $request_filename) {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }
}
```

Maybe there's a better way that doesn't require `if`...

[According to nginx pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Check_IF_File_Exists):

> Using `if` to ensure a file exists is horrible. It's mean. If you have any recent version of Nginx you should look at `try_files` which just made life much easier.